# Haskell example how to use ifdef CPP language pragma?

Tags: haskell

I tried using `ifdef` in the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print "hello"
  #ifdef APP_DEBUG
    print "test"
  #endif
```

However the result is:

```
x.hs:6:3: error: Variable not in scope: (#) :: IO () -> t1 -> t0
  |
6 |   #ifdef APP_DEBUG
  |   ^

x.hs:6:4: error:
    Variable not in scope: ifdef :: t2 -> (a0 -> IO ()) -> [Char] -> t1
  |
6 |   #ifdef APP_DEBUG
  |    ^^^^^

x.hs:6:10: error: Data constructor not in scope: APP_DEBUG
  |
6 |   #ifdef APP_DEBUG
  |          ^^^^^^^^^
...
```

Where am I going wrong?

I can't seem to find sufficient info about this in ghc's docs here: [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/utils.html?highlight=ifdef](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/utils.html?highlight=ifdef)

All I found was:

> #if ⟨condition⟩, #ifdef ⟨name⟩, #ifndef ⟨name⟩, #elif ⟨condition⟩, #else, #endif, #error ⟨message⟩, #warning ⟨message⟩ Conditional compilation directives are passed unmodified to the C program, C file,
> and C header. Putting them in the C program means that appropriate
> parts of the Haskell file will be skipped.

Comment: You should write these at the start of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directives are written at the start of the line, so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print "hello"
#ifdef APP_DEBUG
  print "test"
#endif
```

The C preprocessor runs *before* the Haskell compiler. It thus does *not* understand Haskell and will for example remove a certain code fragment (in this case if `APP_DEBUG` is not defined).

As [@chi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70158162/haskell-example-how-to-use-ifdef-cpp-language-pragma/70158202?noredirect=1#comment124021057_70158202), writing the hash (`#`) as the first line is sufficient, so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print "hello"
#   ifdef APP_DEBUG
    print "test"
#   endif
```

is possible as well.

When compiling, the `APP_DEBUG` flag can be set like so:

```
ghc -DAPP_DEBUG x.hs
```

Comment: I've seen some code "indenting" the directives using `#    ifdef X`. This is legal since all we really need is the `#` of the directive starting at the very beginning, the spaces after it do not matter. Whether this actually makes the code more readable is arguable, I guess.

Comment: @chi: yes, the `#` should be written on the first colum afaik, then it can contain an arbitrary amount of spaces/tabs/....